# Combine fields that has same value in views

Tags: views

Current view

[image]

What I want to achieve

[image]

The data are from 2 different entityforms. And then I merged them in my view.
As you can see, in date row, two data(05/29/2014) has the same value.
I want to merge the same value then the field of the 2nd date will align to the first date.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'group by' option in views?

Under display, you can select to group by date for example.

[image: Group By screenshot in views]